# RTK Query POST method not working on Django REST server

Tags: react-native, django-rest-framework, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I am trying to login a user with RTK Query mutation on a Django REST server and I receive the 405 status with a  "Method "GET" not allowed" error, although the method I am using is 'POST'.

**- apiSlice.ts: **

```
 baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ 
               baseUrl: baseUrl,
               prepareHeaders: (headers, { getState }) => {
                  const token = (getState() as RootState).auth.token
                  if (token) {
                     headers.set('authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)
                  }
                  return headers
               },
            }),
 endpoints: build => ({
        loginUser: build.mutation<ITokenRes, IAuthCredentials>({
            query: (authCredentials) => ({
                url: 'users/token',
                method: 'POST',
                body: authCredentials
            })
        })
    })
```

Beckend code:
**- views.py:**

```
class CreateTokenView(ObtainAuthToken):
    '''Create a new auth token for user'''
    serializer_class = AuthTokenSerializer
    renderer_classes = api_settings.DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES
```

**- serializers.py:**

```
...
class AuthTokenSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    '''Serializer for the user authentication onject'''
    email = serializers.CharField()
    password = serializers.CharField(
        style={'input_type': 'password'},
        trim_whitespace=False
    )

    def validate(self, attrs):
        '''validate and authenticate the user'''
        email = attrs.get('email')
        password = attrs.get('password')

        user = authenticate(
            request=self.context.get('request'),
            username=email,
            password=password
        )
        if not user:
            msg = 'Unable to authenticate with provided credentials'
            raise serializers.ValidationError(msg, code='authentication')

        attrs['user'] = user
        return attrs
...
```

**- urls.py:**

```
...
urlpatterns = [
    path('token/', views.CreateTokenView.as_view(), name='token'),
    ...
]
...
```

Comment: Please also show your `baseQuery`.

Comment: @phry, I added the baseQuery above in the question. In the meantime, I investigated more on the backend, and CreateAPIView (https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#createapiview) and ObtainAuthToken are for create-only endpoints. Is RTK Query doing some sort of sanity check of the URL before doing the actual POST?

Comment: Your browser might send an OPTIONS request to check for CORS, but apart from that it will send a POST - you can see that in your browser's network devtools